# I want to add the button on the page editor and post text editor in new WordPress Gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress, hook, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to add the button on the page editor and post text editor in new WordPress version

I am using this code to add the button of the page and post editor in word press.

```
add_action('media_buttons','wpbeautify_add_sc_select',11);
function wpbeautify_add_sc_select(){
    echo '<a title="FotoPress" data-editor="content" class="button" id="wpbeautify-editor-button" href="#"><img src="'.WPBEAUTIFY_URL.'/img/icons/logo.png"> FotoPress</a>';
}
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

With WordPress 5 and Gutenberg, the media buttons no longer exist. What you will likely need to do is to create a new block for your media type. I would recommend looking at the [Gutenberg Block API Reference](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/) and [how the core/image block was implemented](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src/image) as a guide.